# Reloading the complete page in angularjs after setting a $scope value

Tags: html, angularjs

My application has a login page(**login.html**) and a welcome page(**welcome.html**). Both these pages are loaded inside a **Main.html** using **'ng-view'**.

When a user try to access the path

> http://localhost:8080/MyContext/login

user will be redirected to a login page, where he can enter his credentials and login. Once used logged in successfully, a scope variable($scope.user) is set and the application redirects to welcome.html

> $scope.user=user;

before that I am initializing the same scope variable as null at the beginning of the controller.
There is a navigation bar at the top of Main.html. I am hiding it if the 'user' is not available using '**ng-show**'. This is because I want to show this nav bar only to logged in user.

So I am expecting it to be shown for welcome.html. That is not happening. I believe the ng-view is not reloading the entire html(Main.html) page. How can i solve this?

**Main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MainModule">
<head>
<base href="/Utility/">
<title>UTILITY</title>
<link
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
    src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.6.2"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script data-require="ngstorage@*" data-semver="0.3.6"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="login/login.service.js"></script>
<script src="welcome/welcome.controller.js"></script>
<link href="login/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">




</head>
<body>

    <div ng-show="user">
        <!-- nav bar container -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UTILITY</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false">Drop Down 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                            </ul></li>

                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false">Drop Down 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>


    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {

    var mainModule = angular.module("MainModule", [ "ngRoute","ngStorage" ]);

    mainModule.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/login", {
            templateUrl : "login/Login.html",
            controller : "LoginController"
        }).when("/user/:username", {
            templateUrl : "welcome/welcome.html",
            controller: "WelcomeController"
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : "/login"
        });

        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });

}());
```

**login.controller.js**

```
(function() {

    var loginModule = angular.module("MainModule");

    var LoginController = function($log, $scope, $sessionStorage, UserService, $location) {
        $scope.user = null;

        var userFound = function(userData) {
            $scope.user = userData;
            $scope.message = "Successful Login";

            //store the user information here for session management
            $sessionStorage.user = $scope.user;

            //window.location.replace("/user/"+$scope.user.userName);
            $location.path("/user/"+$scope.user.userName);
        };

        var onError = function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.message = "Invalid User";
        };

        $scope.submitLogin = function(username, password) {
            UserService.getUser(username, btoa(password)).then(userFound,
                    onError);
        };

    };

    loginModule.controller("LoginController", LoginController);

}());
```

**welcome.controller.js**

```
(function(){
    var loginModule = angular.module("MainModule");


    var WelcomeController = function($window, $scope){

        $scope.initWelcome = function(){
            $window.location.reload();
        }
    };


    loginModule.controller("WelcomeController", WelcomeController);

}());
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics. $scope is not a singleton available everywhere. Each controller instance has its own scope (inheriting from the parent controller scope). So storing something in the login controller's scope won't make it available in the root scope used by your menu. This is fundamental stuff about angular. Try reading a good tutorial/book.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much. I moved the user to $rootScope and it is working fine. I started with angular 10 days back. Even though I have seen $rootScope, I dint tried to understand what exactly is its use. For sure, I will try my level best to grab the basics. It will be really great if you could suggest some books.